# Using iproute2 in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 14.04, networking

When you're adding a static route to `/etc/network/interfaces`, how can you use iproute2 commands instead of net-tools commands? For instance, I added the following line:

```
post-up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0
```

to my `interfaces` file and rebooted, but didn't seen the effect in the new routing table.

Is my syntax wrong or am I forced to used net-tools in 14.04-LTS? I know `/etc/rc.local` is one solution, but I'd rather keep networking stuff all in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Use either `pre-up` (before the interface comes up), `up` (after the interface comes up), `down` (before the interface comes down) or `post-down` (after the interface comes down) followed by the command you want to run. In your case, you'll likely want to use `up` and `down`.

Here's a block that I use for assigning an IPv6 address to my internal network:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        up ip -6 addr add 2001:DB8::/64 dev eth0
        down ip -6 addr del 2001:DB8::/64 dev eth0
```

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose before that line is a `iface eth0 inet <static|manual|dhcp>`
`post-up` should run the command only  after the interface comes up, to do so there is no need to reboot, just `ifup eth0`.

To better understand the problem post your `interfaces` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete PDF about route in Linux. Included IPv6. "iproute2" is the future tool for network configuration. http://www.ime.usp.br/~rbrito/docs/lartc.dbk.psom.pdf

[Atualização] I think that only script can do this. Try this. http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.11

Comment: Please edit your question to only include the relevant parts of that document. Also link-only answers are discouraged.